# Heisenberg's uncertainty and conservation of momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics

This is probably conceptual confusion on my part, please bear with me.

I shoot a laser straight ahead for 100 m, where it projects a spot on a screen. Each photon has some momentum; most of the momentum is in the forward component, and the perpendicular component is seen in the fact that the spot is wider on the screen than immediately after exiting the laser aperture.

Now, I put a slit in front of that same laser. The spot turns into a wide smear.

Now, if I understand correctly - I reduced delta x, so delta p increases because of uncertainty principle. But that implies that the momentum if individual photons is changed: that the perpendicular component of the momentum vector is increased.

How can that happen without violating conservation of momentum?

I saw similar questions being asked, but couldn't find one that actually explains this specific problem.

Comment: "How can that happen without violating conservation of momentum?" Presumably the "slit" can transfer as much momentum as needed... Only the entire isolated system of photons-plus-slit needs to have its momentum conserved.

Comment: Thank you, hft. That was my intuition too - but I'm not sure of it. If we put this in vacuum at zero g, would the slit slowly be forced to open up, or start floating in a given direction?

Comment: Yes, the partition with the slit could move. But on average it does not seem like it would move in the transverse direction since those changes in momentum seemingly would cancel out. Certainly the radiation pressure would cause it to move in the direction of the beam if it was not held fixed. In most partition/slit thought-experiments it is implicitly assumed that the partition with the slit is held fixed. In real experiments the partition/slit object can either be "held fixed" or can be so large that it doesn't appreciable move.